# GeolocationPositionError { code: 1, message: "User denied geolocation prompt" } - while developing Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, geolocation, mozilla

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

i am developing extension for Firefox for android + windows.
Above code works perfect in browser (Mozilla nightly for android) and shows (alert + console) my currant position, but when I apply the same code in my Mozilla extension (add-ons) to get device location is shows error on same browser.

in my **popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", documentEvents, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var port = browser.runtime.connect({
    name: "Sample Communication",
  });
  port.postMessage("userExist");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showeroro,{timeout:10000});
    function showPosition(position) {
      console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    }
    function showeroro(rer){
      console.log(rer);
    }
```

in my **console**

```
code: 1
​
message: "User denied geolocation prompt"
```

I have allowed geo location in android apps setting and browser also
i have changed all option, timeout,maximumAge,enableHighAccuracy but doesn't work